# Roll back current block to a prior block

Tags: parity

For testing purposes I want to create some blocks on my computer, not broadcast them to the network, and then rollback my current block in Parity.

In git you would do it like this:

1. Edit some files
2. `git commit -am 'First test commit'`
3. Make more edits
4. `git commit -am 'Second test commit'`
5. `git reset --hard HEAD~2`

That is exactly what I want to accomplish in Parity. For this question I am only concerned about the rollback part.

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/53003/parity-create-testing-transactions-and-blocks

Comment: Maybe you can do it in ganache

Comment: @WilliamEntriken By not broadcasting it to the network do you mean a private network? if so check out https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Private-network , it talks about setting up your genesis file which you set to be your 'rollback' block.

Comment: This is not a private network. I will use the main net then add a few blocks to my node for testing. Then I will obliterate them.

Comment: The motivation for this question is testing smart contracts that are already deployed. More information on that is at https://0xcert.org/news/live-testing-smart-contracts-with-estimategas-william-entriken-tadej-vengust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't rollback blocks, as of [yet.](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues/4324)**

One possible way to do this would be to be to have a script that performs a basic transactions every few seconds, similar to something referred [here](http://const%20Web3%20=%20require(%22web3%22);%20const%20web3%20=%20new%20Web3(new%20Web3.providers.HttpProvider(%22http://localhost:8545%22));%20%20const%20src%20=%20%220x123...%22;%20const%20dest%20=%20%220x456...%22;%20%20setInterval(%20()%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20web3.eth.sendTransaction(%7Bfrom:src,%20to:dest,%20value:%20web3.toWei(1,%20%22ether%22)%7D);%20%7D,%2012000);).

you can than just delete your blocks using something like `parity --light db kill` and then re-syncing to current state with `parity --light`.