# Parity create testing transactions and blocks

Tags: blockchain, parity, synchronization, security, testing

For test purposes, I would like to make test blocks including test transactions against main net.

For example I would like to make a transaction that sends one ether from 0x1234567... to 0x99999999... Assume for a minute that 0x1234567... does actually on main net have one ether plus gas fees available to send.

I would like to:

1. Disconnect from network syncing
2. Prepare this `send` transaction
3. Sign it (using a bogus private key)
4. Mine a block on my client including that transaction (using a difficulty=0 proof of work)

This would require to temporarily disable two security features of Parity to make this work:

1. Transaction signature checking
2. Block proof of work difficulty checking

Is it possible to perform testing in this way?

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/53002/roll-back-current-block-to-a-prior-block

Comment: Parity is open source so you should be able to modify it to disable verification of transactions and blocks.

Comment: The motivation for this question is testing smart contracts that are already deployed. More information on that is at https://0xcert.org/news/live-testing-smart-contracts-with-estimategas-william-entriken-tadej-vengust

Comment: Ganache allows forking of an existing blockchain and to generate new transactions from accounts without the private key, but is is written in javascript. It should be technically feasible to do something similar with parity.